# Is there a way to set sensitivity label in Excel using Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which is generated using Pandas dataframes. I want to add a sensitivity label such as "Public", "Confidential" etc. in Python to the excel file.

[This link shows the normal way of adding the sensitivity label in Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/sensitivity-labels)

But, I want to accomplish the same thing using code.

OpenPyxl does provide a way of adding a password, but not a sensitivity label.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#protect) and i am not sure how to do it with pandas

or

you can change mode of your file when it created by using `os` package `chmod`

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

book = Workbook('file/path')
sheet = book.add_worksheet('worksheet_name')

# Add separate format for unlocked cells
unlocked = book.add_format({'locked': 0})
# Protect all cells in your sheet by default
sheet.protect()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above answer just protects the file/workbook/sheets. I found this link today: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/. I want the same thing in Python where I can read and modify the sensitivity label.

Comment: @Akshay did you find a solution to this with xlsxwriter?